# What is the name of this type of chord?

Tags: chords

It is like a regular A major with A C# and E, however, the C# has been moved up or down an octave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An open chord, open voicing. As opposed to a close voiced chord, where the notes are as close to each other as possible. Close = A, next C# up, next E up. Open = maybe A, next E, then C#.

Also, have a look at drop voicing, it may be of interest.

In your scenario, with C# down an octave, it's first inversion, but up an octave, still root position.

Answer (score 1):

They are also called Spread Triads